# Chain rule with multiple variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I am given $t(r, θ) = u(r \cos θ, r \sin θ)$, and I need to find $t_r$ and $t_θ$. I know that I need to apply the chain rule as $t$ is a composition of $u$ and another function, but how? I'm confused since $u$ takes two inputs. Do I differentiate separately for each of the two inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
t_\theta = \frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta} = 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} +
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} = -r\sin\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + r\cos\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
$$

you should interpret $\partial u/\partial x$ as the derivative of $u$ with respect to its first argument. Similarly for $y$